# NTLM Authentication for Linux server

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I have created micro service in nodejs and hosted on Linux server.
Now my requirement to do authentication from window system.

Means:- Once I call my login service its will do NTML auth and get window system login username and validate with my Database.

Kindly also advice, that with are the right approach to get window user detail either client side or server side. Both code is running on linux server. Client side code in angularjs and server side code in nodes.

Which is the best practice to get window system login credential/Browser credential.

Comment: Currently I am doing NTLM auth validation in server side in nodejs and I am getting error is Unexpected NTLM message Type 3 in new connection for URI "your end point". Before reaching my main service. That means its throwing error from server.js

Comment: Here is the code for server.js  app.use(ntlm(
    {
         debug: function() {
             var args = Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments);
            console.log.apply(null, args);
        },
         domain: 'Domain Name'
     }
 ));

Comment: Did you find a solution?